# Rendering video overlay with other unity cameras

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I have a question about video overlay function of tango in unity.

I want to display video overlay image with NGUI elements.
When I turn on 'Enable video overlay' options in TangoApplication script, displays of other camera in unity scene are disappeared except UI created by Unity itself.(OnGUI and UGUI componets)

Is there a way to use other unity cameras with video overlay?
please, answer.
Thank you.

Comment: You mean play video as overlay?

Comment: No, I mean video overlay function for tango AR